# Accents (destabilizing rhythm) Justin Kauflin

Tags: rhythm, jazz, polyrhythm, accent, latin-jazz

In this video

at 2:10 Justin Kauflin plays these accented chords and I really cannot figure out exactly what the rhythm is. Can anybody hear what he is doing?

Comment: Hi H. Walter. Transcription questions are off-topic on the main site, but try the chat room. There are a number of us who enjoy doing them.